# How to remove enumerated chapter latex in lyx

Tags: lyx, chapters, enumerate

I found an example of template's Lyx and I work fine with it, so lets explain what I'm doing:
I'm writing a book's intership this later start by 3 chapter wich aren't numerated for example here:
[image]
if I place my cursor upon the title of chapter the dropdown menu (where we found the section, chapter, section ...) show me chapter not chapter* so the output is:
[image]

you noticed here we haven't an enumerated chapter for example **Chapter 1** Dédicas.
in this case is very well.
I show ather example but with enumerated chapter in the same document :
[image]

you look here Chapter 4 but its output will be Chapter1:
[image]
and if I place again my cursor the dropdown menu show me chapter too.
very well too :).
but I have a latter chapter that's a general conclusion:
[image]
I want its output is not enumerated chapter like the above one chapter "Dedecase", its output like this:
[image]
my problem is I want the later chapter without enumeration, I tried with chapter* but this is not indicated in the Table of Content.

for my dropdown menu is:
[image]

how I can resolve it and thanks.

Comment: @scottkosty yes it works thanks, but how can I vote your response ?

Comment: Well, I think it's best to mark this as a duplicate. We're waiting for @Werner to post an answer on that question so we can mark this as a duplicate of it.

Comment: More importantly, I'm glad to hear it works!